# Decoding Morse Code problems

Tags: vb.net

I've been struggling with how to complete this assignment for quite a while now and decided I need some help. I have to convert morse code to english and output all possible translations to a listbox (even gibberish). 
Searching has turned up a lot of various threads but nothing useful as they're either not in this language or they're outdated (VB6) code.
The assignment states:

> Using the typical dot (.) and dash (-) for a written representation of the code, the word ...---..-....- in Morse code could be an encoding of the names Sofia or Eugenia depending on where you break up the letters:
>   ...|---|..-.|..|.- Sofia
>   .|..-|--.|.|-.|..|.- Eugenia

where the pipe is simply to show how the string is broken up.

I have tried "For Each" loops, "For" loops, writing to text files and reading back, splitting strings by 1 to 4 characters, a Select Case method and all combinations of the above I could think of with no luck.
My For loops result in sets of 26 of everything, but no words, just series of blank spaces and then a single letter 26 times, followed by that letter twice 26 times, and so on and so on.
Text files and splitting the strings by one or two characters result in either E, A or T for output, each on its own line times the number of iterations in the string, and splitting the string by three or four characters results in the same or an IndexOutOfRange error if the string doesn't evenly divide.
I've come back to the closest thing that I've coded to actually working, but still the output results in just the English Alphabet being output.

I'm using a Linq query this time around and would appreciate any help in figuring out how to iterate through the strings properly to do what the assignment is asking.

Here is my code thus far:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Dim MorseCode() = File.ReadAllLines("MorseCode2.txt")

    Private Sub input_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles input.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub output_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles output.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub help_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles help.Click

        'Displays the Morse Code and English letter equivalents
        Process.Start("MorseCode.txt")

    End Sub

    Private Sub translate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles translate.Click

        Dim userText As String = input.Text
        Dim temp As String
        Dim word As String

        'Search the users entry for possible translations
        Dim query = From line In MorseCode
                    Let data = line.split(","c)
                    Let engLtr = data(0)
                    Let code = data(1)
                    Select engLtr, code

        For Each code In query
            If userText.Contains(code.code) Then
                temp = code.engLtr
                word = String.Concat(temp + temp)
                output.Items.Add(word)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm pretty sure my error is in the .Concat call but nothing I've tried has resolved the issue.

Thank you for any pointers you can give me!

Edit to add Pseudo Code:

1 - Read input string

2 - break string into individual elements 1 symbol each, match symbol to letter, send to temp, concat strings into word, output each word to listbox

3 - re-read string breaking into two symbols each "..."

4 - "..." three symbols each "..."

5 - "..." four symbols each "..."

Comment: Eew, they're teaching VB? Gross. As for the assignment, it's tail recursion in a method that returns an enumerable of strings.  Yield statements would make this very clean.  "Find all characters that match the start of the string.  For each, call the same method again passing in the remaining string, then concatenate each returned result with this character and yield it to the immediate caller."  It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Will some school still teach cobol so what? you should remove your first sentence....

Comment: @Will Would it be "cooler" if they were teaching C# or Java? 'Cos those languages are VERY similar to VB.Net.

Comment: About your pseudo code: This will give you `.|.|.|-|-|-|etc` and `..|.-|--|etc`, but what about `..|.|---|etc`?

Comment: Therein is the problem, I attempted to use the If statements with each substring method to get all possible string combinations but it either put me into an infinte loop or just crashed the application entirely.

Comment: I've also tried the Select Case methods, which I have pasted here
http://pastebin.com/rPwWvJcN
but again, it doesn't iterate through the strings properly.

Comment: Threw together a two minute solution and found out that the permutations are pretty astounding. A certain four letter word you might know, spelled out in morse code, results in ~4700 possible combinations of letters.  That's nutty.

Comment: Thank you @Will for the point to the recursion methods, I'll give that a try and see if I can come up with a working solution

Comment: *Therein is the problem, I attempted to use the If statements...* ... There is the problem again: You are trying to use code *before* having a pseudo-code algorithm that work. That only makes your problem harder, not easier. Break your problems into small pieces and work on them one by one. First, find an algorithm that gives you *all* the permutations of the given morse code. Don't think about implementing it yet, and don't think about translating the dots and dashes to letters yet. One problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given an answer [here] and was able to implement the idea into my own program. Thank you to everyone that helped me out![1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a368ea63-37da-40b0-a61a-cc4a0dfc6b02/decoding-morse-code-problems?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 5):

> I have tried "For Each" loops, "For" loops, writing to text files and reading back, splitting strings by 1 to 4 characters, a Select Case method and all combinations of the above I could think of with no luck.

That's like saying *"I want to prepare a delicious meal, and I have tried sugar, meat, milk, salt, a gas stove, an electric stove, cleaning the kitchen, a frying pan, a fork and all combinations of the above I could think of with no luck."*

What you are obviously missing is *a recipe*. In computer science terms, that's *an algorithm*. I suggets that you do the following:

1. Step away from the computer. Take a piece of paper and a pencil.
2. Try to solve the problem by hand. Take the example `...---..-....-` and try to find all the possible meanings.
3. When you are done, think about *how* you solved the problem. What did you do to ensure that you do not miss any of the possible meanings? Try to write down the steps that you took in plain English. That's your *algorithm*.
4. *Now* you can start translating your algorithm into your programming language of choice.

If you have trouble with any of these steps, I suggest that you start a new question and ask about this point *specifically*. Don't forget to mention what approaches you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, well where I'm stuck is getting the iterations through the input morse code correct. Paper is one thing, I don't crash or throw exception errors like this code does. 
I split the strings via the substring method, similar to "i = 0 to userInput.Substring(0,2) step 2"
in my for loops and that doesn't work. I had four of those inside if statements at one point to split the strings by the possible lengths of the morse equivalent of the english letter.

Comment: So, now I'm back to the code above, which does recognize each set of code characters and outputs the associated letter, just doesn't iterate through the string to produce a word. This is where I'm stuck, and that is what I asked. I don't believe asking a separate question for the same material is beneficial in any way, however I do appreciate the response.

Comment: @Stryke_the_Orc: I see. Let's start with your algorithm, then. Can you add it to your question (in plain pseudo-code)? Then we can go over it and find out if it correct. If it isn't, all attempts to put it in code are in vain.

Comment: Along with the recursion, which in this case is going to be massive, I would do a check to make sure its a valid character since not all combinations will be valid it can help you reduce some of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lang = {}
Concealer = {}
Reveal = {}
bottle = []
Mess1 = []
Mess2 = []

with open('69_Morse.txt', 'r') as translate:
    for line in translate:
        L, M = line.split()
        Lang[M] = L

secret = open('SECRET.txt', 'r')
glasses = secret.read()
bottle = (glasses.replace("\n", " \n ")).split(" ")
secret.close()

for i in range(0, len(bottle)):
    if bottle[i] in Lang:
        Mess1.append(Lang[bottle[i]])
    if bottle[i] == "\n":
        Mess1.append(bottle[i])

for i in range(0, len(Mess1)):
    if Mess1[i] in Reveal:
        Mess2.append(Reveal[Mess1[i]])
    else:
        Mess2.append(Mess1[i])
Final = ("".join(Mess2))

with open("CodeBook.txt", 'r') as rosetta:
    for line in rosetta:
        a, b = line.split()
        Concealer[a] = b
        c, d = line.split()
        Reveal[d] = c

f = open('69_MSG.txt', 'w')
f.write(Final)
f.close()


#Second file of code

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(20201123)

RandNumb = []
Code = []
RandLet = []

AlphaNum = {1: }

while len(RandNumb) != 26:
    val = np.random.randint(1,27)
    if val not in RandNumb:
    RandNumb.append(val)
for i in range(0, len(RandNumb)):
    RandLet.append(AlphaNum[RandNumb[i]])

with open("MorseCode.txt", 'r') as Morse:
    for line in Morse:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        Code.append(line[2:])



f = open('69_Morse.txt', 'w')

for i in range(0, len(RandLet)):
    f.write(RandLet[i] + " " + Code[i] + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of the code you've provided.  Either a brief description of the changes (if this is a modification of the OPs code) or some indication of how it is different.